# Google play connect failed

Tags: android, google-play-services

Recently, I got a problem using Google Play, you can find the log below:

```
06-15 13:12:08.827  2942  6113 E CheckinTask: Checkin failed: https://android.clients.google.com/checkin (request #0): java.io.IOException: Rejected response from server: invalid hardware identifier: "DP7C Pro-SGA1" is not a valid device
06-15 13:12:08.827  4590  5984 D FotaUpdate: SdcardUtil:getExternalStorageStateExt: Environment.getExternalStorageState = mounted
06-15 13:12:08.829  2942  6113 V CheckinService: No Subscriptions found on the device
06-15 13:12:08.830  4590  5984 D Environment: getStorageVolume,  volume:StorageVolume:
06-15 13:12:08.830  4590  5984 D Environment:     mStorageId=65537 mPath=/storage/sdcard0 mDescriptionId=17040808 
06-15 13:12:08.830  4590  5984 D Environment:     mPrimary=true mRemovable=false mEmulated=true mMtpReserveSpace=10 
06-15 13:12:08.830  4590  5984 D Environment:     mAllowMassStorage=false mMaxFileSize=0 mOwner=UserHandle{0} mUuid=null 
06-15 13:12:08.830  4590  5984 D Environment:     mUserLabel=null mState=mounted 
06-15 13:12:08.830  4590  5984 D Environment: getStorageVolume,  volume:StorageVolume:
06-15 13:12:08.830  4590  5984 D Environment:     mStorageId=131073 mPath=/storage/sdcard1 mDescriptionId=17040806 
06-15 13:12:08.830  4590  5984 D Environment:     mPrimary=false mRemovable=true mEmulated=false mMtpReserveSpace=0 
06-15 13:12:08.830  4590  5984 D Environment:     mAllowMassStorage=true mMaxFileSize=0 mOwner=null mUuid=null 
06-15 13:12:08.830  4590  5984 D Environment:     mUserLabel=null mState=removed 
06-15 13:12:08.831  2942  6113 I CheckinService: Checking schedule, now: 1465992728830 next: 1465992763827
06-15 13:12:08.831  2942  6113 I CheckinService: active receiver: disabled
```

I have 3 questions:

1. Does Google Play `checkinservice` verify series number & ro.product.device while connecting?
2. What's the naming rule of it? Will any other parameter be checked?
3. Can the device connect to Google Play with the default series number "0123456789ABCDEF"?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Google Play's access is granted by approved devices. If you have changed you device name in the build.prop file to something that it does not recognize the it will not allow you in. If you did not change the name of your device you may need to do a factory reset to correct the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The property "ro.product.device" should not contains any blanks.
This is a problem with the "Human Verification".